# Binary tree max sum level - better design?

Tags: java, algorithm, queue

I have written some code for finding a level in a binary tree, having a maximum number of elements. I have a few questions:

1. Is it a good design? I have used 2 queues but the total sum of elements both queues store will be less than n. So I think it should be OK.
2. Can there be a better design?

---

```
    public class MaxSumLevel {  
    public static int findLevel(BinaryTreeNode root) {      
        Queue mainQ = new Queue();
        Queue tempQ = new Queue();
        int maxlevel = 0;
        int maxVal = 0;
        int tempSum = 0;
        int tempLevel = 0;
        if (root != null) {
            mainQ.enqueue(root);
            maxlevel = 1;
            tempLevel = 1;
            maxVal = root.getData();
        }           
        while ( !mainQ.isEmpty()) {         
            BinaryTreeNode head = (BinaryTreeNode) mainQ.dequeue();
            BinaryTreeNode left = head.getLeft();
            BinaryTreeNode right = head.getRight();
            if (left != null) {
                tempQ.enqueue(left);
                tempSum = tempSum + left.getData();
            }
            if (right != null) {
                tempQ.enqueue(right);
                tempSum = tempSum + right.getData();
            }           
            if (mainQ.isEmpty()) {
                mainQ = tempQ;
                tempQ = new Queue();
                tempLevel ++;
                if (tempSum > maxVal) {
                    maxVal = tempSum;
                    maxlevel = tempLevel;
                    tempSum = 0;
                }               
            }           
        }
        return maxlevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty complex. What’s the “level” (since you are obviously not using the usual definition by returning an `int`)? Does it correspond to the depth of a node? If so, there’s a much simpler solution.

Comment: @Konrad, yes level means depth. Thanku

Comment: You definitely over-complicated things. Simpler solutions do exist.

http://www.leetcode.com/2010/04/maximum-height-of-binary-tree.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323036/tail-recursive-function-to-find-depth-of-a-tree-in-ocaml 

Note that you could change the data structure such that it keeps the depth of every node as well as the max depth (or better yet, a reference to the deepest node) at all times. This will result in a bit more space, a bit more time, but will make your problem very easy - a simple `O(1)` function call.

Answer (score 2):

My initial criticism is that your method doesn't have javadoc comments that state *clearly and unambiguously* what the method is supposed to do.

Why am I saying that?

Well, mainly because your Question has exactly the same problem!  You say:

> I have written some code for finding a level in a binary tree, having a maximum number of elements.

This is bad description of what you are (apparently) trying to do:

- The word "level" usually refers to the distance of a node from (say) the root of a tree.  But you apparently mean the "height" of the entire tree.
- The phrase "having a maximum number of elements" is unclear.  What are you talking about?  How does this affect the problem?  (I don't see a maximum number of elements parameter ... or any reference to this in your code.)

So why does this matter?

Because I (the reader) should not have to read through your code to try to figure out the problem you are trying to solve.  Especially if your implementation is non-obvious ... which it is ... and possibly contains mistakes that might lead me to think it is solving a different problem than you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

First,  I notice that you are not using generics; I would prefer `Queue<BinaryTreeNode>` over simply `Queue`.
You could use the standard Java [Queue interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html). The [LinkedList implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) should provide all you need for this snippet.

Second, I'm a little surprised that you use iteration; a recursive solution would be a lot more intuitive, and is almost exactly the same as what you would get if you were to use a `Stack` instead of a `Queue`. And it looks like changing from `Queue` to `Stack` would not change the result of the computation.

It looks like you are both calculating `maxLevel` and `maxVal`, but only returning `maxLevel`. Trying to calculate both smells like premature optimization; I would prefer to write separate methods for these calculations.
Drifting somewhat off-topic, but Java 8 is scheduled to have lambda expressions, so you might then be able to have one tree traversal method and pass it appropriate lambda expressions.